# Setting WCF ClientCredentials in MVC project using unity Dependency Injection Container

Tags: c#, wcf, dependency-injection, unity-container

I was wondering whether you thought this or something similiar would be possible with unity?  I want to inject the username and password credentials for the the WCF Service reference OrderServiceClientClient() i am using in my curent project..

```
container.RegisterType<IOrderServiceClient, OrderServiceClientClient>(
   new InjectionConstructor(
      new InjectionProperty("ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName", "test"), 
      new InjectionProperty("ClientCredentials.UserName.Password", "password")));
```

is something like this possible?

EDIT:

looking into the service reference the defination looks like this for the class:

```
class ProductMasterServiceClientClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<com.luzern.co40.web.pm.wsProductMasterService.IProductMasterServiceClient>, com.luzern.co40.web.pm.wsProductMasterService.IProductMasterServiceClient
```

And the parent class ClientBase class contains the definition for the ClientCredential member..

I dont want to replace the Whole ClientCredential member, i just want to set the 2 propertys username and password on it!

EDIT 2!!

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
public partial class OrderServiceClientClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<com.luzern.co40.web.pm.wsOrderService.IOrderServiceClient>, com.luzern.co40.web.pm.wsOrderService.IOrderServiceClient {

    public OrderServiceClientClient() {
    }

    public OrderServiceClientClient(string endpointConfigurationName) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName) {
    }

    public OrderServiceClientClient(string endpointConfigurationName, string remoteAddress) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress) {
    }

    public OrderServiceClientClient(string endpointConfigurationName, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress) {
    }

    public OrderServiceClientClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(binding, remoteAddress) {
    }

    public bool GenerateInvoice(int orderId, string email) {
        return base.Channel.GenerateInvoice(orderId, email);
    }

    public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<bool> GenerateInvoiceAsync(int orderId, string email) {
        return base.Channel.GenerateInvoiceAsync(orderId, email);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you shows us the code for class OrderServiceClientClient and related objects?

Comment: its a generated service reference from a WCF service

Comment: ive made an edit above! thanks!!

Comment: You're still not showing the code for OrderServiceClientClient....

Comment: Sorry Rui, ive added it there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I have a fix.. Im going to create a partial class of my service reference and add a new constructor which takes login credentials of the ClientCredential as a parameter, and then i can just inject as normal string parameters!